# Which Statistical Model to describe data?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

[image]

Hello, I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this question.

I believe this is a **Poisson Distribution** because many of the properties are satisfied with this data. There is no possibility of it being **Normal distribution** and it cant be even be **Binomial Distribution** because that is only used when there are only two outcomes which is not the case here.

The problem is that how can I find out **Lambda i.e. mean** to prove my suggestion is appropriate?

Is it really Poisson or am I missing anything to find out the mean value.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in thinking that the underlying process is Poisson. To find an estimate for $\lambda$ you should use the sample mean $\bar{x}$. To find $\bar{x}$ in this case take the sum of the number of particles times the number of observations. $(0\cdot 34) + (1\cdot 46) + (2\cdot 38) + (3\cdot 19) + (4\cdot 4) + (5\cdot 2) + (6\cdot 0)=205$. Now we just divide by the total number of observations, $34+46+38+19+4+2=143$, so we get $\frac{205}{143}$ as an estimate for $\lambda$

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Tony S.F., Really appreciate your kind support and prompt response. :)

Comment: While Poisson ends being a good assumption, you should do a reasonableness check to see if the sample mean and variance are close, because they are *equal* for a true Poisson distribution. In this case they are, with the variance a bit less than the mean. That then means you should consider a binomial distribution, which always has variance less than mean. Your rationale for rejecting the binomial is incorrect: better is that there is no reason to think that $n=5$ is a good real-world upper bound for particles in a filter if you could take more samples. So Poisson wins in the end!

Comment: Thank you trb456. I wanted to ask how can I test whether my suggestion appears to be valid?

Should i use poisson formula on P(X=4) for instance? and calculate probabilities. Someone told me that I can compare theoretical probabilities with observed ones in Chi-Square but I don't know how to do that. Thank you in advance